# Como passar dados de um JTextField para um campo Date do Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, swing, jtextfield

Peço encarecidamente que me ajudem a resolver um problema de inserção de dados do tipo Date (SQL) para cadastro de novos alunos no projeto de Crud desenvolvido por mim no código abaixo. O método contendo o comando INSERT INTO não insere novo cadastro no banco de dados porque o texto digitado no formato dd/MM/yyyy obtido na Jtextfield não é aceito como dado de formato Date em SQL.

```
package grafico;

import static com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.Type.String;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import sistema.Conectora;

public class Tela extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public Tela() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        c = Conectora.conectora();

    }

    public void cadastrar() throws ParseException{
        String consulta = "INSERT INTO alunos (aluno, , nascimento, mae, pai, sexo, serie) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);";




        try {
            ps = c.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setString(1,campoAluno.getText());
            ps.setDate(2, new Date(campoNascimento.getText()));
            ps.setString(3,campoMae.getText());
            ps.setString(4,campoPai.getText());
            ps.setString(5,campoSexo.getText());
            ps.setInt(6,(Integer.parseInt(campoSerie.getText())));
            ps.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cadastrado com sucesso!");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você não apresentou um código que seja **[mcve]** e nem o problema enfrentado foi explicado direito, então não da pra tirar muitas conclusões especificas. Mas batendo o olho no teu código, percebi que há um erro justamente nas datas, que já foi respondido aqui.

Comment: Desculpe, já tratei de melhorar a pergunta. Porém o problema resolvido na pergunta semelhante à qual você associou a minha como duplicado é um pouco diferente, pois no caso da pergunta do outro usuário a data obtida é a do sistema, já na minha situação, trata-se de um texto obtido de um JTextField.

Comment: Também já foi respondido no site, veja a outra pergunta adicionada as duplicatas